# Difference between busy waiting and spin lock in OS?

Tags: operating-system

Can Anyone give the detailed explanation about the difference busy waiting and spin lock in OS (operating system) ?

Please give the explanation in layman language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put:

*Busy waiting* is a technique in which a process repeatedly checks to see if a condition is true (from Wikipedia).

*Spinlock* uses the above technique for the purpose of checking if a lock is available.

These 2 SO answers explain nicely what is a spinlock and when one should use it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1957464/6098812

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1456261/6098812